# Highly unusual matching error

Tags: issues

One of my users created a petition: Both he and I responded and it appended our responses to the wrong records. I wasn’t logged in and it tried to write to an {surname matching mine]. I suspect that this is the first A. Ross and it is only matching surnames. It appends my data to the existing record.

I just re-submitted my petition signature and it over wrote it again...
Re-submitted petition after changes - Logging Details

```
Top of Form
Change to Mrs Peter Ross made by on 2015-12-14 10:00:03:

Field
Changed From
Changed To
Sort Name (id: 1945)
Ross, Alison
Ross, Peter
Display Name (id: 1945)
Mrs Alison Ross
Mrs Peter Ross
First Name (id: 1945)
Alison
Peter
Modified Date (id: 1945)
2015-12-14 09:15:43
2015-12-14 10:00:03
Source Record (id: 1375)
7
Activity Type ID (id: 1375)
Petition Signature
Subject (id: 1375)
Petition to xxx xxx
Activity Date (id: 1375)
2015-12-14 09:58:53
Activity Status (id: 1375)
Completed
Priority (id: 1375)
Normal
Test (id: 1375)
false
Auto (id: 1375)
false
Is this activity a current revision in versioning chain? (id: 1375)
true
Activity is in the Trash (id: 1375)
false
Campaign (id: 1375)
12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the default unsupervised dedupe rule you have? it should probably have first+last+email if you want to be on the safe side and avoid incorrect merging